# Html Editor Template

Tags: mvc-editor-templates, html-editor

I have a editor template DisplayConfig. In DisplayConfig

```html
@model  string

<input id="@(Model)_DisplayOrder" class="DisplayTypeConfigurator" type="number" />
<input id="@(Model)" class="DisplayTypeConfigurator" type="checkbox" />
```

I want to call this template in my view and send string so i get different id for every textbox.
In my view

```
@Html.Editor("Tab_Info_Product", "DisplayConfig")
```

I do not want to send the value through my model.
I want the result like

```
<input id="Tab_Info_Product_DisplayOrder" class="DisplayTypeConfigurator" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Html.IdForModel()` to construct the ids of your `<input>` tags.

```
<input id="@Html.IdForModel()_DisplayOrder" class="DisplayTypeConfigurator" type="number" />
<input id="@Html.IdForModel()" class="DisplayTypeConfigurator" type="checkbox" />
```